# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length() on php artian serve

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, xampp, php-extension

I tried everything on the stack overflow to get rid of this error.

I created a `laravel project in xampp` and when i run the command

```
php artisan serve
```

This error shows:

> "Call to undefined function
> Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()"

I already uncommented the open ssl extention and set extension path ext.

I tried this on differnt local development servers like xampp, uniserver etc. Everything shows the same issue.

I even put the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in roor folder and restarted the apache. Tried artisan key generation. I've tried every possible answers found on stack overflow. Still getting this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel are you using? what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: i installed the composer and created a laravel project composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog using this.

Comment: @lagbox composer version Composer version 1.10.9 2020-07-16 and php 7.4.5

Comment: you uncommented the extension where? there are multiple different configurations for PHP and what root folder are you referring to?  i would assume running `php -m` does not list 'openssl'

Comment: @lagbox the open ssl extension in php. ini file is uncommented